Convertir el formato de una cadena de números a otro separado con guiones en mysql
¿Es posible convertir una cadena de caracteres numéricos como este 04 00121001735 a este 4-121-1735 en MySQL? ¿Cómo sería la consulta?
La cadena se divide en tres números.
La primera es que no debe tener 0 a la izquierda, Ejemplo 04 a 4
El segundo son los siguientes 5 dígitos sin 0 a la izquierda. Ejemplo 00121 a 121
El tercero son los últimos 6 dígitos sin 0 a la izquierda. Ejemplo 001735 a 1735
El resultado debería ser 4-121-1735

Dado que las posiciones son fijas, es bastante sencillo.
Puedes valerte de

substring() para extraer partes fijas de la cadena
cast() para convertir a números esas partes. En este caso, uso unsigned como tipo de destino. Esto tendrá como efecto quitar los ceros a la izquierda.
concat() para armar el resultado final. La llamada a esta función, con números, promoverá de manera automática estos números a su representación en cadena (ya sin ceros). Si quieres, puedes hacer la conversión a mano de vuelta con cast() o convert().

Como siempre, el código habla más que mil palabras:
select concat(
           cast(substring(numero, 1, 2) as unsigned)
         , '-'
         , cast(substring(numero, 4, 5) as unsigned)
         , '-'
         , cast(substring(numero, 9, 6) as unsigned)
       ) numeroProcesado
  from (select '04 00121001735' numero) q

fiddle
Esto da como resultado:
numeroProcesado
------------------
4-121-1735


Gracias, tanto su respuesta como la de Marcos me funcionan.

A partir de MySQL 8 podemos utilizar la función REGEXP_REPLACE(), la cual podes utilizar para dar formato a cadenas utilizando expresiones regulares.
Primer paso:
Utilizar una RegExp para dar formato a la cadena sin quitar lo ceros:
^(\d{2}) (\d{5})(\d{6})$


Descripción: 2 dígitos, seguido de un espacio, seguido de 5 dígitos, seguido de 6 dígitos.

Aplicada en la consulta sería:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
  '04 00121001735',
  '^(\\d{2}) (\\d{5})(\\d{6})$',
  '$1-$2-$3') AS numero_formateado;

Resultado:



numero_formateado




04-00121-001735



Segundo paso:
Utilizar otra RegExp para quitar los ceros de la cadena formateada:
(^|-)0*


Descripción: La cadena empieza con cero o más "0" o hay un guión seguido de cero o más "0".

Aplicada en la consulta sería:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    '04 00121001735',
    '^(\\d{2}) (\\d{5})(\\d{6})$',
    '$1-$2-$3'
  )
 '(^|-)0*', 
 '$1'
) AS numero_formateado;

Resultado:



numero_formateado




4-121-1735



Demo

Este método me funciona también. Muchas gracias
